# How to emulate a slow client (browser)?

Tags: javascript, client, performance

Is there any way to slow down the responsiveness of the client (browser)?

One of our testers can reproduce slowness on his machine. His machine is low enough spec and is similar to many real customers.
We have a fat client, javascript heavy, alot of event processing. We fear there maybe a regression but it's unreporoducable on developer machines.

The issue is text entry on input controls, tabbing around the app would appear to get delay and the text entry sometimes omits the first character typed by the user.

Development cannot reproduce, is there any way to slow down the client or the browser?

Comment: you could tell the OS to give the browser's process a low priority (and if that's not enough, make sure there is something crunching some CPU at the same time), and if there are multiple cores involved you could allow access to only one core for example, although to properly model bad performance, there is nothing more real than a genuinely poor machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser may have relevant options.

For instance, Firefox has:

- [`javascript.options.jit.content`](https://wiki.mozilla.org/JavaScript%3aTraceMonkey) – set it to `false`;
- `javascript.options.mem.gc_frequency` – set it to a lower number.

Comment: These options can be accessed by going to the address `about:config` in Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a virtual machine with very limited memory, or just purchase a crappy PC. They wont cost that much!

Comment: Having as many old machines, with out of date OS's and software,  as possible is a real help in testing real code. As you say, they are cheap to buy, and a good use for old hardware you have outgrown.

Answer (score 3):

Run something like HyperPI on the machine to slow it down: http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=211 (simple, unelegant solution)

Or run Crysis in the background.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the windows SDK installed, you can use the consume.exe tool to generate load on the machine.

It can generate CPU/memory/disk/page file/kernel pool load.