# How to emulate a slow client (browser)? Mac

Tags: browser

I'm looking to simulate a slow browser:

The question is the same as this one but the answers given on that question are out of date.

[How to emulate a slow client (browser)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117884/how-to-emulate-a-slow-client-browser)

I'm looking for updated answers pertaining to the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Opera, or Safari.

Thanks.

Comment: i would use a VM and limit its resources for this task ...