# Elegant way to emulate slower browser on fast machine

Tags: javascript, performance

What might be a really elegant way to emulate slower browsers if you are developing on a really strong machine and want to explore how your *JavaScript* performs on slower machines?

I found suggestions on [How to emulate a slow client (browser)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117884/how-to-emulate-a-slow-client-browser), but none seem to be the silver bullet, let alone the answers by now are old. It would be neat to be able to say "this is how this would run on a machine with this or that chipset and memory" rather than just be able to slow it down..

Comment: Use a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, I think a virtual machine would give far more realistic results than anything else...

Comment: What's wrong with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5117907/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi to name one thing, you pay the performance penalty of the virtualization itself, so I assume it does not represent the actual performance you are trying to emulate with it. It is also too terse and uses obscene language :-) let's see what else new comes up.

Comment: There are no silver bullets!

Comment: @matt: Well if you don't want to virtualize, then you can only fire up an old machine.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is use a virtual box with low RAM for example 1gb for windows seven, and also limit the number of cores to one.

optional you could limit the bandwidth of the virtual machine

Edit:
for the windows licenses, Microsoft  offers free virtual machines for debugging at this [site](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/linux/)

Comment: No Windows licenses, sorry. I assume they're required for VM's.